# Get all pattern Word fom a Text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

If I have a text, how can I get all the strings with a certain pattern from the text? For example I want all the strings with this patters:

> The word **`CER`** followed by **`any number`** followed by one of
>   this characters **`;`**, **`,`**, **`.`** or ***`space`*** .

For exemple from the text bellow I wold like to have in an array the following results : CER123 , CER23 , CER01 , CER24

> Lorem CER123 ipsum dolor sit amet, quod copiosae CER23,CER01;CER24 insolens et usu, vis CER34ERD ut saperet civibus accommodare.

I've tried this:

> preg_match_all("/CER[0-9*]?/",$content,$m);

but it returns : `CER1` , `CER2` , `CER0` , `CER2` and `CER3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+`, add a capturing group and create a character class for the characters you require after the value you need to get:

```
preg_match_all('/(CER[0-9]+)[;,.\s]/',$content,$m);
                 ^        ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fM2eY3/1)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `(CER[0-9]+)` - Group 1 capturing the parts of text you need:

  - `CER` - a sequence of literal  characters `CER` (**NOTE**: If you need whole word `CER` only, after a non-word char or at the start of the string, add word boundaries: `\bCER\b`)
  - `[0-9]+` (=`\d+`) - 1 or more digits
- `[;,.\s]` - any char inside the character class: `;`, `,`, `.` or `\s` (whitespace - replace with a space if you only mean a regular space).

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/jIZoH1):

```
$re= '/(CER[0-9]+)[;,.\s]/';
$content = "Lorem CER123 ipsum dolor sit amet, quod copiosae CER23,CER01;CER24 insolens et usu, vis CER34ERD ut saperet civibus accommodare."; 
preg_match_all($re, $content, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```